# How to resolve INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY on Android Things Project

Tags: android, controls, interrupt, gpio

I try to control a GPIO Port on Android App using the Android Things Project.
But when I run this app through ADB(on Android Studio), the following message is issued..

> Installation failed with message
>   INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY. It is possible that this issue
>   is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is
>   present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

How can I resolve this problem?

Android version is Android 5.1.1(API 22)
My Android App is coded according to the web site which explains the Android Things Project(https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/gpio.html#managing_the_connection)

The build.gradle for app is the following.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kr.iges.wallpad.gpiotest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    provided 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.1-devpreview'
}
```

And AndroidManifest.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kr.iges.wallpad.gpiotest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And JAVA Code is

```
package kr.iges.wallpad.gpiotest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.things.pio.PeripheralManagerService;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "GpioTest";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PeripheralManagerService manager = new PeripheralManagerService();

        List<String> portList = manager.getGpioList();

        if (portList.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No GPIO port available on this device.");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "List of available ports: " + portList);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Do you know the solution for this problem?

Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 0):

Add the things shared library entry to your app's manifest file:
This worked for me. Make sure you add uses-library within the application tag only.

    
    ...